# Response Does not work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, request, httpresponse

This is my code which is used, i have passsed parameters and URL like this

```
    let headers = [
        "token": "il8uStkZjG3JPefPcjiGIwQ99TGpIL1nmQMyrv0e",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      //  "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        //  "Postman-Token": "97d77826-fcc0-4efd-b01c-e4b1f829e713"
    ]

    let body = ["appointment_time_from": "asdsadasdasdasd"] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.request(STORE_NEW_ORDER_WITH_PREVIOUS_ADDRESS , method : .post , parameters : body , encoding : URLEncoding.default, headers : headers ).validate().responseSwiftyJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {

        case .success:
            let data = response.value
            print(data ?? "" )

            print("Validation Successful")

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "obj" : [

  ]
}
```

> **Note:** It works perfectly in Postman:

Comment: `let data = response.result.value as? [String:Any]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure in which format you are getting response:

Generally it works like this:

Assuming that the response is in `[String:Any]`

```
let urlString = "https://httpbin.org/get"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["foo": "bar"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  
response in
  switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let dataResponse = response.result.value as! [String:Any]
                    print(dataResponse)

                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this:-

```
let headers = [
    "token": "il8uStkZjG3JPefPcjiGIwQ99TGpIL1nmQMyrv0e",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  //  "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    //  "Postman-Token": "97d77826-fcc0-4efd-b01c-e4b1f829e713"
]

let body = ["appointment_time_from": "asdsadasdasdasd"] as [String : Any]

Alamofire.request(STORE_NEW_ORDER_WITH_PREVIOUS_ADDRESS , method : .post , parameters : body , encoding : URLEncoding.default, headers : headers ).validate().responseSwiftyJSON { (response) in

    switch response.result {

    case .success:
        if let data = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
          if let objectArray = data["obj"] as? NSArray {
          }
         }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }

}
```

If it doesn't work then try by changing encoding type to JSONEncoding.default

Also try by removing encoding paramter

Comment: // output error 
responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(500))

Comment: Its internal server error is its working in postman.. also check if its working then whats in form URLEncode or FormData

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code.Hope it's help to you

```
func GetDataAPI()
{
    let url = "your URL"
    var param : [String : AnyObject] = [:]

    param = ["appointment_time_from": "asdsadasdasdasd" as AnyObject]
    print(param)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding()).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        print(response)

        if (response.result.value != nil)
        {
            //your code
        }
        else
        {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: // output 

FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))